# Deserialization of Complex json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

```
    public class Example1
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public List<List<Datum>> data { get; set; }

        public string msg { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
    }
```

Json:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "pdfString": "JVBERi0xLjcKJeLjz9M"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "msg": "Data Successfully Retrived"
}
```

I want to access the value of the pdfstring here but when I am  trying this 
I am getting  null value  here.I want to access the value of the pdfstring  here.

```
var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

Example1 dat = (Example1)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText, typeof(Example1));
string pdfString = dat.data[0][0].value;
```

Comment: Throw your `Datum` class away and use a `Dictionary<string,string>` for the Example1.data property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead of `List<Datum>`.

The correct class definition for your JSON is here:

```
public class Example1
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<List<Dictionary<string, string>>> data { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

Please look on my [.NET Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AQ6vEV) for full code example.

Also you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for generating of your C# classes.